# Spring integration channel message count

Tags: spring, integration

I have 2 questions. Here they are:

1. Is there any way to determine the number of messages waiting to be
   processed in a spring integration channel while the number of
   customers keep increasing along the time?
2. In the app context, I want to be able to define x instances of
   bean y which x and y, both consumes from channel p, programmatically
   increase or decrease the consumers based on the load.

There is an example showed in spring 2gx but it used `rabbitmq` to determine load.

Answer (score 0):

- For 1), Spring Integration channels are just beans like any other bean.  Assuming that you're using a standard pollable channel, you can autowire it in by name and then get the number of messages waiting:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/channel/QueueChannel.html#getQueueSize()

You may also be able to introspect this through JMX if you want.

- For 2)... To do that, you'll want to use an AOP proxy on top of an object pool, then wire the proxy into (what I assume is a) Service Activator.  Those properties can be externalized with a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.  So, as an example:

  ```
  <bean id="propertyPlaceholder" 
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
      <property name="systemPropertiesMode" value="2" />
      <property name="locations" value="classpath:my_config_params.properties" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="myBusinessObjectImpl" class="com.mycompany.whatever.impl.MyServiceImpl"
        scope="prototype" autowire-candidate="false" />

  <bean id="myBusinessObjPool" class="org.springframework.aop.target.CommonsPoolTargetSource">
      <property name="targetBeanName" value="myBusinessObjectImpl" />
      <!-- THIS IS THE KEY.  myconfig.params.poolsize is the name of the property in the my_config_params.properties above. -->
      <property name="maxSize" value="${myconfig.params.poolsize}" /> 
  </bean>

  <bean id="myBusinessObject" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
      <property name="targetSource" ref="myBusinessObjPool" />
  </bean>

  <int:channel id="myInputChannel">
      <int:queue size="500" />
  </int:channel>

  <int:service-activator inputChannel="myInputChannel" ref="myBusinessObject" method="processMessages">
      <int:poller max-messages-per-poll="10" fixed-rate="5000"/>
  </int:service>
  ```

This also allows you to make the Service Activator stateful. 
Obligatory link to object pooling functionality:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop-api.html#aop-ts-pool